# Good bootstrap UI for selecting multiple boxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a state dropdown with 50 states and I want to be able to select multiple states (it's like a UI component to select multiple states to blacklist). What's a good UI component in bootstrap for this?

I was looking at [this](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) and at the multiselect, but it seems like selecting 25 states might be a bit clunky looking. Is there anything better?

Comment: Here's another one that is fairly similar http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/ pretty easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

Group the states as per region (E, W, N, S). And you could have a dropdown with the regions, and depending upon this selection, populate the states dropdown.